# Can't read CSV file with pgAdmin4, could not open file - Permission denied

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin-4

I started to learn PostgreSQL and pgAdmin 4. I have a problem with reading CSV file from desktop. I looked all over the web and this website but I could not find the answer. I get this error:

```
ERROR: could not open file "C:\Users\Jasmina\Desktop\OnlineRetail2.csv" for reading: Permission denied
SQL state: 42501
```

I have tried to use `/copy` but still does not work. Whats the problem, what am I doing wrong?4

```
CREATE TABLE Public."My_OnlineRetail"(InvoiceNo int, 
                    StockCode varchar(100), 
                    Description varchar(100), 
                    Quantity int, 
                    InvoiceDate timestamp, 
                    UnitPrice float, 
                    Currency varchar(10), 
                    CustomerID int, 
                    Country varchar(100));

SELECT * FROM Public."My_OnlineRetail";

COPY Public."My_OnlineRetail" FROM 'C:\Users\Jasmina\Desktop\OnlineRetail2.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

Comment: probably the account that the PostgreSQL server runs under can't access files under your personal user directory. Don't forget the SQL server runs as a service with a different identity. Other user identities generally cannot access your user directory unless they are admins. Try putting the file somewhere neutral on the disk, and check that permissions on the file and the parent folder will allow the SQL account to access it.

Comment: How to do that? My file is on desktop, and everyone can access to it. I tried to put the file in other folders, and it still does not work\

Comment: who is "everyone" exactly? Other user accounts on the same PC generally don't have access to your desktop, unless you seriously messed up your filesystem permissions (which you _really_ shouldn't). And when you "put the file in other folders", did you check the permissions of the file/folder as I mentioned? Did you check what identity the SQL service uses and make sure that identity has read access to the folder and file? You haven't confirmed any of this, yet claim it doesn't work. I can't advise you without detailed info on the situation.

Answer (score 0):

For those still looking for an answer, in my case under Windows Server, the account (or default user) the PostgreSQL server runs is '`NETWORK SERVICES`'.

You can check this by going to

> 'Services' -> 'postgresql...' -> Properties (via Right Click) -> Log
> On (Second Tab)

.

You can then add permissions for the account on the file you wish to COPY to 'Read'.

Comment: I see the log on tab but dont see how I add permissions

Comment: You have to open WindowsExplorer, right click on your file -> Properties -> Security tab -> Edit Permissions -> Add -> input 'Network Services' -> Check Names -> OK -> Select Read permissions for 'Network Services